# Create a group box around certain controls on a web form using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have three controls on my web form of three drop down lists.

I want to create a graphical "box" around these controls. The reason for this is that selecting these controls would be "STEP 1" of my process. So I want to put a box around these controls and call it "Step 1"

How would I go about doing this with CSS?

Example:

> [image: box around form elements]

Answer (score 106, accepted):

A `fieldset` with a `legend` provides a visual and semantic grouping for form controls. You can then style this as desired with CSS. A `fieldset` is somewhat unique in that the `legend` is capable of visually interrupting the border of its parent `fieldset` (possible with other elements, but difficult).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/NUMcr/1/

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Group 1</legend>
    <input type="text" />
    <asp:Textbox runat="Server" id="txt1" />
    <!-- etc -->
</fieldset>
```

```
fieldset {
    margin: 8px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    padding: 8px;    
    border-radius: 4px;
}

legend {
    padding: 2px;    
}
```

Comment: hmmmmmmm, i added the fieldset tag but the controls are not showing up in the box. these controls have a css class attached to them and positioning are all set to them. could this be an issue?

Comment: It might be. Fieldset is just a container so it should be a fixable problem. Try setting `position: relative` on the fieldset, and/or try removing the CSS on the controls temporarily and see if they show up.

Answer (score 14):

There is the `fieldset` HTML element, which is made for this specific purpose: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/fieldset.  If you are set on using CSS only, you could do something like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

    <h1>Step 1</h1>
    <div style="border: 1px solid #000000;">
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

You could then style the `h1` (or whatever type of HTML element you'd like to use for the header) and the `div` containing the input elements.

Answer (score 4):

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Personalia:</legend>
    Name: <input type="text"><br>
    Email: <input type="text"><br>
    Date of birth: <input type="text">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: add little bit explanation to your answer